# Displaying the error message with an Azure AD B2C custom policy for password reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the steps in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121920/how-to-give-a-custom-error-message-if-on-forgotten-password-page-of-azure-b2c) and also the AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations).

However, I cannot get the error message to display.

I have an email link for a custom password reset flow. The link validates the user so I don't need the user to validate the email address as per the normal password reset flow.

When the user clicks the link, I set a custom attribute so that the user cannot click the link twice. In this case I want to display an error message.

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordReset-Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddress" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>    

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="UpdateFlag" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

The AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId writes a flag to indicate the journey has been done.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
                    <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Process complete blah.</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                </TechnicalProfile>
```

This has a validation TP AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>            
                    </Metadata>
                    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>          
                    <PersistedClaims>
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
                    </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dummyObjectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="EnsureCompletedIsTrue" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
```

This has an OutputClaimsTransformation EnsureCompletedIsTrue.

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="EnsureCompletedIsTrue" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Completed" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

So if extension_Completed is True it should throw the error message "Process complete".

I have checked that the flag is true but I never see the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue), it assert the claims value is as expected, otherwise throw error. You are asserting it against a "true" but shouldn't it be against "false"?

If the link has never been used, the claim value is false. The validation is done to assert that is false. Once it's being used, the claim value should be true (I believe you'd handle this somewhere). And if the user use the link agains, the claim value now is true, and the assertion would throw because it expects a false value.

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="EnsureCompletedIsTrue" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Completed" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
    </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```